# I want to apply bootstrap thumbnail style for the picture library images

Tags: html, css, listview, sharepoint, thumbnails

I am using Sharepoint 2013.

I added a picture library to a page and used the thumbnail column to show the image on Page created using Sharepoint 2013. I want to apply bootstrap thumbnail style for the picture library images.

I tried this CSS coding. It works. but it applies to all the images.

Kindly suggest for the selector for the thumbnail picture only for the sharepoint list

Answer (score 0):

Add the class selector ".ms-listviewtable" before your CSS code.

```
<style>
.ms-listviewtable img{

}
</style>
```

Comment: I suggest you provide the custom css style for further research.

Comment: I use only bootstrap.min.css version 4